# What happens to Clifford in Ad Astra?

Tags: plot-explanation, ad-astra

In the end of *Ad Astra*, Clifford asks Roy to unhook him. Roy reluctantly obeys. But in the next shot, they show Roy staring at a bright near Neptune’s rings. Was it his own ship, or is there a possibility that Clifford may have somehow escaped?

If he didn’t escape, why did Clifford want to die? What was the point of it all, if he wanted to continue searching for life?

Answer (score 2):

Clifford considers his mission a failure because he wasn't able to find other life in the universe. Also, he says that Earth is not his home anymore. Moreover, Clifford is a criminal, responsible for the death of his team. If he returns to Earth he'll turn from a hero to an insane villain.

It's unlikely that there's one more ship for Clifford to survive. If there were other ships nearby they'd be probably detected and inspected by Roy. Anyway, the bright object was too far to get to it with a spacewalk.

Comment: Then what was the object?

Comment: @Aditya It's not mentioned in the script or in the movie. Therefore, I doubt it has any significance for the scene. It could be Roy's ship but that's just an assumption. It could also be some activity of Neptune's rings because when Roy uses the rotating antenna to jump into space and looks up the object is not there.

Comment: Well, then that’s a flaw on the movie’s part I guess

Comment: @Aditya some details are left unexplained on purpose, to ask the viewer to use their imagination. Or sometimes it's just not relevant enough to spend screen time explaining. It's not necessarily a flaw.